# Enable Intel SGX (software guard extensions) in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, cpu, intel-amt, sgx

I need SGX support in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS for my [Asus k456Q](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/nb/X456UA/0409_E10295_X456U_X556U_EM_A.pdf) laptop with a Core i7-7500 CPU(which supports SGX) and bios version 303(X456UQK) , but I find no settings related to SGX in the BIOS/Firmware settings.

Intel's website said SGX requires the Intel Management Engine (ME) support, so I installed the ME interface, using the instructions of [this link](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/support/us/en/documents/technologies/intel_amt_linux_enablement_guide_revision_1_1.pdf).

However, the package for LMS (Local Manageability Service) didn't exist. It was removed lately for updating .

**Update :** I could install LMS via packages in arch repo but it can't connect to AMT, it seems to be not enabled. what should I do now? there is no settings in bios for ME or LMS or even SGX, is there a way to communicate with them without bios? updates are available for my bios ([version 304 and 307](https://www.asus.com/supportonly/K456UQ/HelpDesk_BIOS/)) but they didn't say what will change through this updates, can they help? (I haven't update my bios before, it's a little scary!)

Comment: Suggest you look at https://github.com/rainliu20/e9/blob/master/iMX6Q/ubuntu/linux_E9_3.0.35_for_Ubuntu/drivers/staging/mei/mei.txt and https://files.bitkeks.eu/docs/intelme-report.pdf . I was able to find it in the Arch repositories https://www.linuxsecrets.com/archlinux-wiki/wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/AUR.html, but not for Ubuntu, not even at Intel's site https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/search.html?toplevelcategory=none&query=Local%20Manageability%20Service&keyword=Local%20Manageability%20Service

Comment: @K7AAY thanks a lot for your comment, it helped me a lot and I could install the LMS package from the arch repo, but I understood that before installing this package I need to enable the AMT to communicate with ME and there is no settings in bios for ME or AMT, can you help me to find a way communicating with ME or its AMT firmware?

Comment: @K7AAY I have asus k456UQ-A and as I have told I'm using ubuntu 18.04. what's the relation of ME and OS? why they may not exist for linux? As I understood intel-ME is a hardware part different from OS.

Comment: _Fateme Rahmani_, thanks for the update! I've added a bounty to get more help. ME is a CPU within your CPU, explained here: https://www.howtogeek.com/334013/intel-management-engine-explained-the-tiny-computer-inside-your-cpu and here https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000008927/software/chipset-software.html . Asus says there's a K456UQ and a K456UQK, so let's assume it's the former. Is your BIOS version 302? If so, no update required; if not, please advise by clicking [edit] and putting your BIOS in the question. Please do not use Add Comment, please instead use [edit].

Comment: Also created an SGX tag here and over at AskUbuntu.com on a similar question I also elevated with a bonus https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131948/how-to-setup-intel-sgx-on-ubuntu (although that question is not as detailed as yours) . Keep your eye out for an answer there as well. Perhaps someone brighter than I will answer soon; but, if the BIOS which ASUS uses does not support SGX, that's something I doubt can be fixed.

Comment: Where did you find that bios version 303(X456UQK), supports SGX?
It is strange that it supports SGX but there is no corresponding setting.

Comment: @sancho.s, I'm sorry after adding bios version I didn't pay enough attention to the rest of the sentence, I know my intel CPU version supports SGX but I don't know how can I use it.

Comment: My question is where did you read that the BIOS version supports SGX?

Comment: @sancho.s It seems that my BIOS doesn't support SGX!(I'm not sure but I conclude it from BIOS settings) I made a mistake in my question and I edit it after your question. my question now is there a way to use SGX without BIOS support? or BIOS update will help me?

Comment: I added an answer according to your latest update.

Answer (score 1):

Your BIOS does not seem to support SGX.
As per links in comments [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1131948/how-do-i-setup-intel-sgx-on-ubuntu) (there seems to be no point in copying here, as it is a SE site), that seems a mandatory requirement for using SGX.